# Is it possible to use Agent Based Modelling tools such as Netlogo to do network simulation (e.g TCP)

Tags: modeling, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I intend to model using Netlogo. However, I haven't seen any solid reference to using Netlogo for network simulations. I would like to check for simple network parameters like throughput and how changes in agent-set (Network node in the case) can change some network parameters. Is this possible in Netlogo alone? if not, is there any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. The simulation that I want cannot be achieved via NetLogo alone (or rather will be too complex). As NetLogo supports custom extensions, I am now looking into using extensions. I intend to use NetLogo alongside Omnet++ or Opnet. NetLogo will provide the agent modeling capabilities (traffic + GIS extensions) while Omnet++/Opnet will provide the networking simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Netlogo has built in support for graphs. So, it is easy to draw a network of computers/routers and have packets flow around in them.

I once built a simulation of the bittorrent protocol in NetLogo. It is fairly straightforward.

So, yes, it is possible.